# Handling redirecting request in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, request

I am trying to get the data from the url: [autotrader_url](http://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/showcase.xhtml?zip=94536&endYear=2017&Log=0&modelCode1=LEGACY&sortBy=derivedpriceDESC&startYear=1981&makeCode1=SUB&numRecords=25&searchRadius=25&mmt=%5BSUB%5BLEGACY%5B%5D%5D%5B%5D%5D&makeCodes=SUB)
Unfortunately I am not able to handle the redirect.
Here is my code so far.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request({followAllRedirects: true,url:"http://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/showcase.xhtml?zip=94536&endYear=2017&Log=0&modelCode1=LEGACY&sortBy=derivedpriceDESC&startYear=1981&makeCode1=SUB&numRecords=25&searchRadius=25&mmt=%5BSUB%5BLEGACY%5B%5D%5D%5B%5D%5D&makeCodes=SUB"},
function (error, response, html) {
    console.log(response)
   if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("yo");
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log($("title").text());
    $('div.listing-title h2').each(function(i, element){
       var a = $(this);       
       console.log(a.innerHTML);    
       });   
    }
});
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `followAllRedirects: true` option will follow http redirects sent back from the server. It appears that they are not using an http redirect because when you visit that page in the browser it loads a page that says "We're searching for the car that you want" and that page does a client side redirect in the browser using javascript. To follow that kind of redirect you probably have to use something like [phatomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

Alternatively using cheerio(maybe) or some combination of regex you could get the redirect url directly from the source and then make a second request to that url on your own once you have the right url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       atc.create(atc.showcaseRedirect, {
           destinationUrl: '/cars-for-sale/Subaru/Legacy/Fremont+CA-94536?endYear=2017&firstRecord=0&makeCode1=SUB&mmt=%5BSUB%5BLEGACY%5B%5D%5D%5B%5D%5D&modelCode1=LEGACY&searchRadius=25&showcaseOwnerId=68619541&startYear=1981&Log=0',
           queryString: '',
           ....
       }).init();
   });
</script>
```

You just have to grab that `destinationUrl`. Now with all that said, this assumes you aren't breaking any of their terms of use so you should definitely look into that before you move forward.

I'm not sure if its a bug on their end or if they are trying to prevent people from scraping but you need to set a `User-Agent` header to get them to respond so add this to your request.

Here is a full working example:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var firstUrl = "http://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/showcase.xhtml?zip=94536&endYear=2017&Log=0&modelCode1=LEGACY&sortBy=derivedpriceDESC&startYear=1981&makeCode1=SUB&numRecords=25&searchRadius=25&mmt=%5BSUB%5BLEGACY%5B%5D%5D%5B%5D%5D&makeCodes=SUB";

makeRequest(firstUrl, function(err, html) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log('There was a problem');
  }
  // get "redirect" url from page source
  var re = new RegExp("destinationUrl\:[^\,\}]*");
  var redirectUrl = 'http://www.autotrader.com' + html.match(re)[0].replace('destinationUrl: ', '').replace('\'', '');
  console.log('redirectUrl', redirectUrl);
  // make the second request and process the markup with cheerio
  makeRequest(redirectUrl, processFinalMarkup);
});

function processFinalMarkup(err, html) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  console.log($("title").text());
  $('div.listing-title h2').each(function(i, element){
    var a = $(this);       
    console.log(a.innerHTML);    
  });    
}

function makeRequest(url, callback) {
  request({
    // Their page requires a User-Agent to be set.
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'express'
    },
    followAllRedirects: true,
    url: url
  },
  function (error, response, html) {
      console.log(response.headers, response.statusCode);
     if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log("yo");
      callback(null, html);
    }

  });
}
```